# How to add a dynamic view in between items of RecyclerView in android?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, fitbit

I need to add a small strip in between items of a RecyclerView. This strip can come after different number of items in a list. This needs to be done dynamically.
I need to implement something like what FitBit has done:[image]

I also need the first row i.e. the one saying "This Week" to stick on top even if the page scrolls down.

Comment: You have to use two view types. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26245139/how-to-create-recyclerview-with-multiple-view-type) to see how to implement it. It might be a clue to achieve what you want.

Comment: Yes, I have done using that only currently. But one issue still lingers - how does FitBit manage to keep the header row sticking on the top of the screen even if we scroll?

Comment: You can try this [library](https://github.com/timehop/sticky-headers-recyclerview) You can setcustom layouts for the items and headers so I think this is excatly what you are looking for

Comment: Thanks! That answers it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [StickyHeaderRecyclerView library](https://github.com/timehop/sticky-headers-recyclerview)

It is very easy to use

Answer (score 6):

You should use the concept of different view types using [getItemViewType(int)](https://developer.android.com/intl/pt-br/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html#getItemViewType(int)). Then on [onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup, int)](https://developer.android.com/intl/pt-br/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html#onCreateViewHolder(android.view.ViewGroup,%20int)) you can check which type you should inflate/create.

Example:

```
@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    // you should return the view type, based on your own dynamic logic
}

@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
     switch (viewType) {
         // handle each view type accordingly
     }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide a link or an example ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the concept of multiple view types in your `RecyclerView`, Just by using `getItemViewType()`, and take care of the viewType parameter in `onCreateViewHolder()`.

For example you can use below model:

```
    public class Data{
           int field1;
           float filed2;
           int rowType // 1,2,2,...N this will fill by you whenever you will    
                       //creating arraylist for your recyclerview
     }


    public class Custome Adapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {

    ArrayList<Data> mItems;

    class ViewHolderRowType1 extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        ...
    }

    class ViewHolderRowType2 extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        ...
    }

    ....
    class ViewHolderRowTypeN extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        ...
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        return mItems.get(position).rowType; 
        //or
        //return positon%2; // This will based on your condition        
    }

    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
         switch (viewType) {
             case 0: return new ViewHolderRowType0(...);
             case 1: return new ViewHolderRowType1(...);
             ...
             case N: return new ViewHolderRowTypeN(...);
         }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder vh, int position) {

    //Just check which view type is going to bind and then fill the data accordingly in your rows


      if(vh instanceof ViewHolderRowType1){
       // Fill the data for first view type


      } else if (vh instanceof ViewHolderRowType2) {
       // Fill the data for second view type


      } else if (vh instanceof ViewHolderRowTypeN){
       // Fill the data for Nth view type


      }

    }
```

For your sticky "this view weak", you can add it at top of your `RecyclerView` and then handle it by scroll Event of RecyclerView

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to implement such `RecyclerView`

1. Add header in every layout and hide/show based on your requirement(preferable).
2. Or use two different layouts for header and content(not preferable because it can cause problem in total count of items in adapter).

In your custom POJO / GetterSetter class, add one field for `headerStatus`(either boolean or int), to identify whether to show header or not.

Now in adapter override `public int getItemViewType(int position)`.

```html
static final int TYPE_ITEM = 0;
static final int TYPE_SEPARATOR = 1;
@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
 if (mData.get(position).getHeaderStatus() == 0)
  return TYPE_ITEM;
 else
  return TYPE_SEPARATOR;
}
```

Now at the time of inflating the layout in `getView()` you can check the row type by

`int rowType = getItemViewType(position);`

For case 1, you need to visible the header and set appropriate data in it.
For case 2, you need to inflate that header layout and add appropriate data in it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it in "proper" way, without hacks, you should write your own LayoutManager, and handle those cases by hands. It is not as hard as it sounds, but will take some efforts.

Comment: can u please provide any example of layoutManager ?